# Is the 'In the news' section of Stack Exchange's site updated regularly?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, company-page

In the footer of every Stack Exchange site there is a link to [Press](https://stackoverflow.com/company/press), where a page with the title 'In The News' shows a list of news entries talking about Stack Overflow as a company.

I noticed there is a Spanish article from June 2017 also talking about the company: [El genio que convirtió su blog para informáticos en un gigante de internet](https://www.eldiario.es/hojaderouter/tecnologia/software/Stack_Overflow-Joel_Spolsky-programacion-codigo-desarrolladores_0_651635125.html) and it is not listed.

Is it worth suggesting to add it? Is there any requirement (language, importance of the newspaper) to have them added? Or, more generally, is the list updated?

Comment: *is the list updated* ... every 6 to 8 weeks ...